# Authentication failure issue on centos

Tags: centos6, dovecot

I have configured dovecoat on centOs. When i access email through thunderbird or gmail IMAP. everything goes fine. but when i try to configure using sparrow mail client on Mac osx. Server log shows the below error.

```
Nov 16 12:40:07 localhost dovecot-auth: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=info@xyz.com rhost=82.16.29.165
Nov 16 12:40:07 localhost dovecot-auth: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=help@xyz.com rhost=82.16.29.165
Nov 16 12:40:07 localhost dovecot-auth: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=info@xyz.com rhost=82.16.29.165
```

Everytime mail client tries to fetch emails, it just throughs the below log.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "dovecoat", as you call it, is capable of logging authentication steps in considerable detail; I suggest you set

```
auth_debug = yes
```

in your dovecot config.

Without further (or any, actually) relevant information, it's impossible to tell what you did wrong.
It appears to fail to map the login to a valid PAM user; this could be for any number of reasons. user